# How to query jsonb column with spring data

Tags: jdbc, spring-data, jsonb

I have a repository which has a simple query for reading the products:

```
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<Product, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT\n" +
        "   p.id,\n" +
        "   p.locations \n" +
        " FROM product p" +
        " WHERE p.id = :productId \n")
    List<Product> queryProducts(@Param("productId") Long productId);
}
```

The **locations** column in my db has a type of jsonb which is an array of multiple objects and the value somehow looks like this: `[{"city":"New York", "country": "USA"}, {"city":"Madrid", "country": "Spain"}]`
What I would like to do is when querying the products, i want to map the result from p.locations back to java objects which in this case a List inside of my Product object:

**Product.java**

```
mport lombok.Value;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

import java.util.List;

@Value
@Table
public class Product {
    Long           id;
    List<Location> locations;
}
```

**Location.java**

```
import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class Location {
    String city;
    String country;
}
```

When i run the application, i got following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: We need at least one condition
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
> Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
>
> Original Stack Trace:
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlGenerator.buildConditionForBackReference(SqlGenerator.java:311)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlGenerator.getFindAllByProperty(SqlGenerator.java:289)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlGenerator.getFindAllByProperty(SqlGenerator.java:260)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.findAllByPath(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:303)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
> at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy101.findAllByPath(Unknown Source)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.MappingJdbcConverter$ResolvingRelationalPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingJdbcConverter.java:379)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.MappingJdbcConverter$ResolvingRelationalPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingJdbcConverter.java:310)
> at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.MappingRelationalConverter$2.getPropertyValue(MappingRelationalConverter.java:480)
> at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.MappingRelationalConverter$2.getPropertyValue(MappingRelationalConverter.java:461)
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:71)
> at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.MappingRelationalConverter$ConvertingParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(MappingRelationalConverter.java:1164)
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49)
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:301)
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:273)
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:98)
> at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.MappingRelationalConverter.read(MappingRelationalConverter.java:444)
> at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.MappingRelationalConverter.readAggregate(MappingRelationalConverter.java:339)
> at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.MappingRelationalConverter.readAggregate(MappingRelationalConverter.java:302)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.MappingJdbcConverter.readAndResolve(MappingJdbcConverter.java:287)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.JdbcConverter.readAndResolve(JdbcConverter.java:106)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.EntityRowMapper.mapRow(EntityRowMapper.java:82)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcQueryLookupStrategy$PostProcessingRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcQueryLookupStrategy.java:335)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.AbstractJdbcQuery$ConvertingRowMapper.mapRow(AbstractJdbcQuery.java:196)
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94)
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61)
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:733)
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:723)
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:748)
> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:178)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.AbstractJdbcQuery.lambda$createSingleReadingQueryExecution$3(AbstractJdbcQuery.java:165)
> at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.StringBasedJdbcQuery.execute(StringBasedJdbcQuery.java:145)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
> at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)

I guess i need here a custom mapper to convert between jsonb and my internal objects but still don't know how to do that. Can anyone give me an idea? Thank you

i tried google and searched for some solutions but no success